# Extract offset term from glm

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm

I am wondering how to extract the offset term from the following model:

```r
mod <- glm(cyl ~ mpg + disp + offset(log(gear)), family = "poisson", data = mtcars)
```

I would like to write a function `get_offset()` which returns the offset term:

```r
get_offset <- function(x){
  ...
}

get_offset(mod)
#> "log(gear)"
```

`get_offset()` should also return the offset term for the models:

```r
mod2 <- glm(cyl ~ mpg + disp, offset = log(gear), family = "poisson", data = mtcars)
mod3 <- glm(cyl ~ mpg + offset(log(gear)) + disp, family = "poisson", data = mtcars)
mod4 <- glm(cyl ~ mpg + offset(gear) + disp, family = "poisson", data = mtcars)
```

Giving:

```r
get_offset(mod2)
#> "log(gear)"

get_offset(mod3)
#> "log(gear)"

get_offset(mod4)
#> "gear"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could get the attributes from the `terms`

```
get_offset <- function(model) {
     nm1 <- names(attributes(model$terms)$dataClasses)
      if('(offset)' %in% nm1) {
             deparse(as.list(model$call)$offset)
        } else {

      sub("offset\\((.*)\\)$", "\\1", grep('offset', nm1, value = TRUE))
     }
   }

get_offset(mod)
#[1] "log(gear)"
get_offset(mod2)
#[1] "log(gear)"
get_offset(mod3)
#[1] "log(gear)"
get_offset(mod4)
#[1] "gear"
```